# Ruby - What is the difference between range's include and cover methods wrt date ranges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, date-range, rubocop

```
date_range = {:start_date => (DateTime.now + 1.days).to_date, :end_date => (DateTime.now + 10.days).to_date}        
date_range_to_check_for_coverage = {:start_date => (DateTime.now + 5.days).to_date, :end_date => (DateTime.now + 7.days).to_date}        

(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).include?((DateTime.now + 5.days).to_date)        
#true
(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).cover?((DateTime.now + 5.days).to_date)        
#true
(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).include?(date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:start_date]..date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:end_date])        
#true
(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).cover?(date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:start_date]..date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:end_date])        
#false
```

Shouldn't the last line return *true* ?

Why does using *cover?* with date ranges differ from *include?* ?

The reason I am asking is **rubocop** flags a conflict when I use *include?* in place of *cover?*. And clearly, my logic (to check if the range is included in another range) does not work with *cover?*.